# (Python) Flask - why is request.args.get returning none type

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, request

I cant figure out why exactly '`request.args.get`' is returning none. I take input from a form, and when the form refreshes, I expect my input there but it returns 'none' instead.

the two lines of code are

```
student = request.args.get('name')
 grade = request.args.get('grade')
```

`main.py`:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/info', method=['POST'])
def info():
    student = request.args.get('name')
    grade = request.args.get('grade')
    return render_template('results.html', studentid=studentid, student=student,grade=grade)
```

`home.html`

```
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="student" placeholder="John Smith" style="width: 500px;" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fgrade">Final Grade:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fgrade" name="grade" placeholder="90" style="width: 500px;" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit Form">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
```

`results.html`

```
<body>
    
                <td>{{studentid}}</td>
                <td>{{student}}</td>
                <td>{{grade}}</td>
```

Much appreciate anyone's input or help.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Your repeated attempt at vandalising your post, and my repeated reversals, will have been noticed by the system, and moderators will have been alerted. Please - refrain!

Comment: im a student at a university and am attempting to delete my own question because I don't want others copy, this was a mistake and I want to delete it that way my code does not get plaguirized.

Comment: i left enough code for anyone to take a look at the question and understand it, please just leave it like this.

Comment: Keep you question as it is, it is fine and clear. You can't delete since there is one answer with one upvote and you can't vandalize your posts. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sending an **HTTP POST** request from your html page (`method="POST"`), so the parameters are inserted in the body of the request. To retrieve the params you need to use `request.form.get("param_name")`

Comment: thanks for your help, this advice and one of my params was incorrect. Using 'request.form.get' and double checking if my params were correct fixed this issue.